# Sum rows using ROLLUP

Tags: sql, rollup

I have written a query that produces the following results.

The query looks like

```
SELECT
    rlrDivision.strLangue1 AS Division,
    COUNT(p.pkPoste) AS NumbersToAdd,
    SUM(p.iNbPostes) AS MoreNumbersToAdd 
FROM 
    poste p
LEFT JOIN 
    lien_objet_ref_8 lienDiv ON lienDiv.fkObjet = p.pkPoste
LEFT JOIN 
    r_referentiel rrDivision ON rrDivision.pkReferentiel =        lienDiv.fkReferentiel
LEFT JOIN 
    r_libelle_ref rlrDivision ON rlrDivision.pkLibelleRef = rrDivision.fkLib1
LEFT JOIN 
    lien_objet_liste_3 lol3 ON lol3.fkObjet = p.pkPoste AND   lol3.`strContexte`='descriptif/type_contrat'
LEFT JOIN 
    r_liste_editable rle ON lol3.fkListe = rle.pkListeEditable
LEFT JOIN 
    r_libelle_ref rlr ON rle.fkLibelleRef = rlr.pkLibelleRef
WHERE 
    p.pkPoste <> 1
    AND p.iSuppr <> 1
    AND p.iDernierEtatPoste = 2
    AND rlr.strLangue1 LIKE 'Full-time%'
GROUP BY 
    rlrDivision.strLangue1, p.`iNbPostes` WITH ROLLUP
```

This almost produces the correct results. However, I would like to have only one row for each Division, which without the ROLLUP I have. However, I do not have the desired totals. So basically I want what is below but with another row for totals on NumbersToAdd and MoreNumbersToAdd.

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Does it support [`ROLLUP`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I changed my alias names so that it makes more sense now.

Comment: I think you should store that in a temporal table or variable table and then perform two queries, one being a simple `SELECT` and the other doing the `SUM()` of those fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can do `UNION` :

```
SELECT
rlrDivision.strLangue1 AS Division,
COUNT(p.pkPoste) AS NumbersToAdd,
SUM(p.iNbPostes) AS MoreNumbersToAdd 
FROM poste p
LEFT JOIN lien_objet_ref_8 lienDiv ON lienDiv.fkObjet = p.pkPoste
LEFT JOIN r_referentiel rrDivision ON rrDivision.pkReferentiel =        lienDiv.fkReferentiel
LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref rlrDivision ON rlrDivision.pkLibelleRef = rrDivision.fkLib1

LEFT JOIN lien_objet_liste_3 lol3 ON lol3.fkObjet = p.pkPoste AND   lol3.`strContexte`='descriptif/type_contrat'
LEFT JOIN r_liste_editable rle ON lol3.fkListe = rle.pkListeEditable
LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref rlr ON rle.fkLibelleRef = rlr.pkLibelleRef
WHERE p.pkPoste <> 1
AND p.iSuppr <> 1
AND p.iDernierEtatPoste = 2
AND rlr.strLangue1 LIKE 'Full-time%'
GROUP BY rlrDivision.strLangue1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total' as Division
    , COUNT(p.pkPoste) as NumbersToAdd
    , SUM(p.iNbPostes) AS MoreNumbersToAdd 
FROM poste p
LEFT JOIN lien_objet_ref_8 lienDiv ON lienDiv.fkObjet = p.pkPoste
LEFT JOIN r_referentiel rrDivision ON rrDivision.pkReferentiel =        lienDiv.fkReferentiel
LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref rlrDivision ON rlrDivision.pkLibelleRef = rrDivision.fkLib1
LEFT JOIN lien_objet_liste_3 lol3 ON lol3.fkObjet = p.pkPoste AND   lol3.`strContexte`='descriptif/type_contrat'
LEFT JOIN r_liste_editable rle ON lol3.fkListe = rle.pkListeEditable
LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref rlr ON rle.fkLibelleRef = rlr.pkLibelleRef
WHERE p.pkPoste <> 1
AND p.iSuppr <> 1
AND p.iDernierEtatPoste = 2
AND rlr.strLangue1 LIKE 'Full-time%'
GROUP BY rlrDivision.strLangue1
;
```

There are other `ROLL UP` functions available for doing total in query , but not sure if you database would support that , as you haven't mentioned your database name .

Comment: @minatvermaj I am not sure this is acceptable in sqlPro I am getting the error Unknown column 'MoreNumbersToAdd' in 'field list'

Comment: Actually it seems ROLLUP is supported but again not on an alias

Comment: @00robinette I have updated the answer . Can you please check .

Comment: that isn't it either. I will play with it. That query produces 3 extra rows named title with the same numbers as the divisions - so 6, 12, 37 and 9, 12, and 257.

Answer (score 0):

ROLLUP was the correct approach, but since a lot of work was put into figuring out how to properly execute I am answering my own question. Thanks for the input.

```
    SELECT 
    rlrDivision.strLangue1 AS Division,
    COUNT(p.pkPoste) AS NumbersToAdd,
    SUM(p.iNbPostes) AS MoreNumbersToAdd 
    FROM poste p
    LEFT JOIN lien_objet_ref_8 lienDiv ON lienDiv.fkObjet = p.pkPoste
    LEFT JOIN r_referentiel rrDivision ON rrDivision.pkReferentiel =                 lienDiv.fkReferentiel
    LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref rlrDivision ON rlrDivision.pkLibelleRef = rrDivision.fkLib1
    LEFT JOIN lien_objet_liste_3 lol3 ON lol3.fkObjet = p.pkPoste AND   lol3.`strContexte`='descriptif/type_contrat'
    LEFT JOIN r_liste_editable rle ON lol3.fkListe = rle.pkListeEditable
    LEFT JOIN r_libelle_ref rlr ON rle.fkLibelleRef = rlr.pkLibelleRef
    WHERE p.pkPoste <> 1
    AND p.iSuppr <> 1
AND p.iDernierEtatPoste = 2
AND rlr.strLangue1 LIKE 'Full-time%'
GROUP BY rlrDivision.strLangue1 WITH ROLLUP
```